# Deterministic Online Graph Coloring

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science

Hello i tried to prove that every deterministic online graph coloring algorithm is at least O(lg(n)) worst then optimal coloring (for some cases), but i failed to do that. Do you have any solutions or ideas about this problem ?